# Face Orientation weird effect

Tags: texturing, normals

There was a weird effect on my textures that when I set to face Orientation, I got this result.
Any idea what it could cause it?

[image: The face orientation view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks a lot like *z-fighting* caused by too large *clipping range*.

- Either adjust the values in *Clip Start/End*
- or switch to Orthographic view through *View > Orthographic (Numpad 5)*

*Change clipping distance...*
[image]

*...or switch to Orthographic view*
[image]

Comment: Yes, It works! Thank you!