# Materials flickering through other objects

Tags: mesh, materials

Is there any way to get rid of this bane other than remaking everything as a single object? I have several big objects which have smaller panels on them. And when I set materials, the materials of big objects constantly flicker through said panels. The mesh does not intersect with the panels in any way. Is there any way to stop this from happening ir does Blender always see smaller objects as too thin and not relevant to when it comes blocking the materials of the bigger objects?

[image]

If I move the camera closer, the flickering disappears and everything looks normal.

[image]

Comment: can u pls provide blend file? if they don't intersect/are on same position, this shouldn't happen...

Comment: If those smaller objects are just Planes, try moving them forwards away from the main object very slightly. It sounds as if they're showing Z-fighting by your description. If that doesn't help please share your Blend file so that we can see what's happening.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/311986/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: .. or adjust the clipping range of the view, or the camera, to avoid floating-point error.. please share a representative failing file on https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can have a go at fixing the right problem.

Comment: @RobinBetts Seems like it was clipping range of the view issue, thank you! It was the first time I game object a pretty huge base size, so I suppose the values of working with small models didn't fit this time. I changed the view clipping parameters and the texture flickering disappeared.

Comment: Glad that's a fix! It turns out that it might br fair to call this post a duplicate of others like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/177975/35559).. would it be fair to close it out, do you think?